# changing Log-On Account for service with powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-services, get-wmiobject

I have csv file with mass data - service name, computer name, account name.

I wrote a script that:

- takes the data from the file
- renames for each service the name of the user who runs it
- generates a password for it
- updates it in AD and in the service itself
- then update an external file with a saved password

The problem is that I get a `null` error for the command `Get-WmiObject` in the stage **Load List Servers to $ServiceObject**

I'd love help if possible.
I think there should nested foreach but can't find where

```
$Computers_list = Import-Csv -Path "C:\PS-Script\Service(sid)_prod.csv" # (CSV file with 3 columns, StartNameCredential, ServiceName, ServerName)
$NameCredential = $Computers_list.StartNameCredential
$ServiceName = $Computers_list.ServiceName
$ServerName = $Computers_list.ServerName
$i = 0

foreach ($ServerName in $ServerName) {

    # Generate Random Password
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
    $pass = [System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(16, 5)
    $ServicePass = $pass

    # Load List Servers to $ServiceObject
    $ServiceObject = get-wmiobject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $ServerName -filter "Name='$ServiceName'"

    # Stop Service $ServiceName
    $ServiceObject.stopservice() | out-null

    # Change $ServiceName Start-Mode
    $ServiceObject.ChangeStartMode("Automatic") #Manual \ Automatic

    # Update Password In AD for $StartNameCredential
    Set-ADAccountPassword -server "sap.technion.ac.il" -Identity $NameCredential -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $pass -Force)
        
    # Change Log-On Account for service
    $ServiceObject.Change($null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $false, $NameCredential, $ServicePass) | out-null

    # Start $ServiceName Service
    $ServiceObject.startservice()

    # Insert $pass into file
    echo $NameCredential[$i] $pass >> SAP_prod_pass.txt

    $i++
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to inspect the objects without entering the loop. Create all the variables at the beginning, then try $ServerName[0] and $ServiceName[0]

Comment: Thank you for your response.
When I check separately it works
When I run all the code, I get null.

Comment: You are iterating wrong. `foreach ($ServerName in $ServerName)`.. If `$ServerName` is the **array** of servernames to loop through (bad variable naming btw..), then use a different variable to iterate like `foreach ($Server in $ServerName)`. Then of course use **that** variable inside the loop on stuff like `-ComputerName $Server`

Comment: As @Theo describes, you should rewrite how you access each element. In general foreach is intended to work as such: foreach($object in $object_array) { do something }. I generated a sample-array and used your naming-convention and it does work for me, but it might depend on version of PowerShell. In any case, change in accordance with proper naming-conventions and try to simply print the scoped object to see that it is not in fact null.